# Google BigQuery Data Extraction

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract data from BigQuery, but I'm not being able to extract all the data, from the beginning, since it aggregates the data per day, in different datasets.

I tried do delete the final part of the source table *"FROM `independent-tea-354108.152182944.**ga_sessions_20230126**`"* but it retrieves an error message.

[image: BigQuery]

Comment: What error message did you received?  does increasing the limit to higher than 1000 helps ?

Comment: see here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables first.